# Julia Gadfly legend for line types

Tags: types, line, julia, legend, gadfly

To insert legends for different lines with different colors I use Guide.manual_color_key

However I couldn't find anything to add legend for lines with same color but with different line types. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It's currently marked as pending feature [in the source code](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/63a0c28af8fbbb8d88857159d6b0b779dc65f024/src/guide.jl#L467).